# Why push() set new sort A-Z?

Tags: javascript

I try to push array in another array with **push()** But push() is set new sort in another array.

How to fix new array don't sort A-Z ?

```
newdata = [];
data = [
  {
    name: "1",
    data: [31, 40, 28, 51, 42, 109, 100],
  },
];
```

**Try push()**

```
newdata.push(data);
```

> Console.log(newdata);

```
[
  {
    data: [31, 40, 28, 51, 42, 109, 100],
    name: "1",
  },
]
```

This I want :

```
[
  {
    name: "1",
    data: [31, 40, 28, 51, 42, 109, 100],
  },
]
```

Live Example:

```js
const newdata = [];
const data = [
    {
        name: "1",
        data: [31, 40, 28, 51, 42, 109, 100],
    },
];
newdata.push({ ...data});
console.log(newdata);
```

Comment: What you've said it does is not what it does (see the result of the runnable example I added by copying and pasting your code), and what you've said it does vs. what you said you want it to do are effectively identical. Although JavaScript object properties *do* have order now, *using* that order is almost always the wrong thing to do. but that doesn't matter in your case, because `newdata` and your original array both refer to the **same object**, so the properties will be in the same order regardless of which array you use to get that object's reference.

Comment: maybe you want: `newdata.push([ ...data]);`?

Comment: @Iosif - Or even `newdata.push(...data)`, it's impossible to tell. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder 

Answer (score 3):

Objects are ordered by insertion order (at least in this case where all the property names are letter based strings and there's no inheritance).

If you copy all the properties from one object into another, then you are going to get the properties in the *same* order.

You *probably* shouldn't care about the order, and if you really do then you *probably* should **use a Map** instead of an object, but if you really want to change the order, then you need to sort explicitly:

```js
const newdata = [];
const data = [{
  name: "1",
  data: [31, 40, 28, 51, 42, 109, 100],
}, ];

const newObject = {};
Object.keys(data[0]).sort().forEach(key => newObject[key] = data[0][key]);
newdata.push(newObject);
console.log(newdata);
```

Comment: Fair point. Updated.